# Find $V ^ {\displaystyle \bot }$

Tags: linear-algebra

In vector space $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$ we have scalar product 
$$\langle\ p,q \rangle = p(-1)q(-1)+p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)$$
We have $V = Lin \{1+x\}$. So I have to find $V ^ {\displaystyle \bot }$!

So I choose $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ and then I use scalar product and got $$\langle\ ax^2+bx+c,1+x \rangle = 2a+2b+3c$$

And that has to be $= 0$. So I express $b$ out of this equation and put in $p(x)$ so then I got $$p(x)=a(x^2-x)+\frac{c}{2}(2x-3)$$

My base is then $\{x^2-x,2x-3 \}$ and I use Gramm - Schmidt process and I got $V ^ {\displaystyle \bot } = Lin \{2x-3, 3x^2-1\}$, but solution is $V ^ {\displaystyle \bot } = Lin \{2x-3, 5x^2-2x -2\}$

Is this wrong, that I got different answers or I have to fix something?

Comment: Note that the condition $b = \frac{1}{2}(-3c - 2a)$ inserted into $p(x) = ax^2 + bx+ c$ yields $p(x) = a(x^2 - x)+ \frac{c}{2} (2 - 3x)$.

Comment: Why bother with Gram-Schmidt? Are your bases required to be orthonormal?

Comment: There is no required to be orthonormal. So I us Gram-Schmidt only if I am looking for orthonormal bases?